# SwiftUI Zooming 2 images with 1 zoom gesture

Tags: swift, swiftui

there are two images on my screen first one has a zoom gesture on it and it zooms fine, I am trying to get 2nd image to zoom as well simultaneously. if I use zoom gesture on the 1st image so far here is my code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var zoomlevel: CGFloat = 1

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("selfie1")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width:150, height: 150)
        
            VStack {
                
                Image("selfie1")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width:150, height: 150)
                    //.padding(.bottom, 100)
                    .scaleEffect(self.zoomlevel)
                    .gesture(MagnificationGesture().onChanged({ (value) in
                        //if value <= 40 {
                            self.zoomlevel = value
                        //}

                      }))
                
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Just put the `.scaleEffect(self.zoomlevel)` on the first image as well.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var zoomlevel: CGFloat = 1

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Image(systemName: "folder")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width:150, height: 150)
            .scaleEffect(self.zoomlevel) // ADD THIS HERE
    
        VStack {
            
            Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width:150, height: 150)
                //.padding(.bottom, 100)
                .scaleEffect(self.zoomlevel)
                .gesture(MagnificationGesture().onChanged({ (value) in
                    //if value <= 40 {
                        self.zoomlevel = value
                    //}

                  }))
            
            }
        }
    }
}
```